# How to enlarge a clicked image with plain JavaScript on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, image, mobile

I'm trying to create thumbnail images that enlarge when clicked. The goal is to have the selected thumbnail enlarge itself to the maximum width of the device. If another thumbnail is clicked, its image will replace that of the currently selected thumbnail. Only one thumbnail can be enlarged at any one time.

The image should span the device's maximum width. Also, I am trying to accomplish this with plain JavaScript (no jQuery), CSS, and HTML.

**JavaScript**

```
function showImage(imgName) {
    document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
    showLargeImagePanel();
    unselectAll();
}
function showLargeImagePanel() {
    document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function unselectAll() {
    if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
    if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
function hideMe(obj) {
    obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img  src="./Images/image.jpg" alt="1.jpeg" style="cursor:pointer" 
      onclick="showImage('./Images/image.jpg');">
<div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
<img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

**CSS**

```
#largeImgPanel {
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0; left: 0; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
}
```

The image does pop up, but it is too large (wider than that of the device), so it does't fit the mobile screen. How do I make it the right size?

Comment: And what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain the image width to the width of the parent container.

```
#largeImg  {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will force the image to be no bigger than the container it's held in, and automatically scale down on smaller screens.

Comment: I did that and it still apear way to large and tall for the mobile device; I see like 1/8 of the picture

Comment: So as per your question, you asked for "no wider than the device".  If you want to also restrict the height, I'd recommend using a CSS media query that limits the height of images for mobile screen resolutions.

Comment: Yes but I did what you told me and the image is still not wide as the device,its original resolution so it appears like 10time to wide for the device

Comment: Most likely because the container it's in is wider than the device screen.  Start from the top of your HTML structure and work your way down.  You need to debug your code in it's entirety, not just snippets.