# Javascript ordered image popup ... can't separate individual popups

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

ok, this is my first stab at javascript or coding in general so I hope this isn't too messy. My code is almost where I want it but I have run into one last problem -

I have a scrolling table of images and I'd like the viewer to be able to click each picture to enlarge it individually. I'm trying to do this through the showImage function as follows:

JS:

```
function showImage(largeimg01) {
document.getElementById("largeimg01").visibility = 'visible';
showLargeImagePanel();
unselectAll();
}

function showImage(largeimg02) {
document.getElementById("largeimg02").visibility = 'visible';
showLargeImagePanel();
unselectAll();
}

function showImage(largeimg03) {
document.getElementById("largeimg03").visibility = 'visible';
showLargeImagePanel();
unselectAll();
}

function showLargeImagePanel() {
document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function unselectAll() {
if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
function hideMe(obj) {
obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

HTML: 
        
        
        
        
        
        Leah Gotchel

```
<!-- javascript here -->

<link href="../wood-site-pagespopup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<a href="../index.html">
<p id="back"> LEAH GOTCHEL </p></a>

<!-- hidden popup images -->

<div id="largeImgPanel"  onclick="hideMe(this);">
<img class="popup" id="largeimg01" src="../images/GUS_4735retweb.jpg"       />
</div>

<div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
<img class="popup" id="largeimg02" src="../images/GUS_5034retweb.jpg" />
</div>


<div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
<img class="popup" id="largeimg03" src="../images/GUS_4735retweb.jpg"  />
</div>

<div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
<img class="popup" id="largeimg04" src="../images/GUS_4735retweb.jpg" />
</div>



<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="../images/GUS_4735retweb.jpg" id="img01"    style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage(largeimg01);"></td>

<td> 
<img src="../images/GUS_5034retweb.jpg" id="img02" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage(largeimg02);">       
</td>
<td><img src="../images/GUS_5060retweb.jpg" id="img03" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage(largeimg03);">
</td>
<td><img src='../images/GUS_5077retweb.jpg'" id="img04" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage(largeimg04);">
</td>

</tr>

</table>
<p id="caption">custom window bench: oak, poplar </p>




</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;}

html {
display:table;
}

body{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}

#back{
font-family: Corbert;
font-style: italic; 
font-size: 2em; 
color: ##006699;
position: relative; 
padding: 30px; 
margin-left: 20px; 
}


img {
padding: 20px;
width: 500px; 
}
a {
color: #006699;
margin: 0 auto;
text-decoration: none; 
}

a:hover {
color: #8b98a7;
}



p {
position: fixed;
padding: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
clear: both; 
margin-left: 20px; 
}


table {
top: 50%
left: 50% 
position: absolute; 
border:none;
}


.popup {
position: relative;
height: 90%;
width: auto;   
overflow: scroll;

}



.largeImgPanel {
text-align: center;
visibility: hidden;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; 
width:100%;
height:100%; 
background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
}

#largeImg  {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

This code is close to what I found here: [How to enlarge a clicked image with plain JavaScript on a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641576/how-to-enlarge-a-clicked-image-with-plain-javascript-on-a-mobile-device)

The popup is functioning - My problem is that, when I call on any one popup, all the popup images appear. The first popup (img01) is blocking the rest so they can't be seen. I think this is because they are all contained in divs with the same "largeImgPanel" id - but if they are not contained in the "largeImgPanel" div then they don't show up at all when I run the function.  How can I change the script so that the function applies only to the specific popup image corresponding to the image that is being clicked?

This is my first post so I apologize if it's nonsensical! Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if I can try to clarify.

Comment: whats in the showLargeImagePanel function? got it. thats your problem

Comment: hi, did you see the page in action? http://www.rachelgallen.com/leahgotchel.html ?

Comment: I did actually do another page minus the deprecated table but my Dreamweaver has crashed! Im out having lunch and left the computer rebooting so I'll post the re-edit later

Comment: actually your other edit is at http://www.rachelgallen.com/leahgotchel1.html

Comment: ideally you would put your name in a header section etc..

Comment: here's a page with a header and footer etc.. you should avoid using absolute positioning where possible! http://www.rachelgallen.com/leahgotchel3.html

Comment: oh ok all great tips!! ty!

Comment: if you ever get over 15 rep, you can return the favour and give me an upvote :) And you get a badge for your first upvote! You can examine the source of the html by just right clicking and going 'View Source', you know that right? so i don't need to post 3 lots of code? lol! Next: media querias! .. seriously .. make it responsive!

Comment: oh by the way, i was a bit baffled as to why exactly you wanted to start the photo slides so far in. If you don't actually want a big gap at the start, see leahgotchel4.html - you know where to go! ;)

Comment: that i will definitely do! and no i didn't know about 'view source' until now but love that!! will look into the other things you mentioned... as for the gap, i'm not sure why that was showing up on your example... on my end the images were always positioned to the left. maybe there was a discrepancy in the css i posted? kind of a cool design though ;)

Comment: yeah your css had left:50% in it and it was like -er why? - so i left it in, but then left it out on the next iteration. css is slightly different (and better) on number 4 i think. You don't need the inline!important on the section, you can take that out, cos its on the ul anyway. i put a wrapper div around the whole lot of the content, just to be neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 4 images are named with the same id, largeImgPanel, so all 4 show when that function is called. Change the id to a class (put a dot instead of a # in your css) and give unique ids to your divs, keeping the class there

That should sort you out, but remember to call the relevant id!

EDIT:

Ok, so here's your WORKING (edited!) code

```js
function showImage(imgname){
var mypic=document.getElementById(imgname);
mypic.style.visibility = 'visible';
mypic.style.zIndex = '20';
unselectAll();
}
function unselectAll() {
if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
function hideMe(obj) {
obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
obj.style.zIndex = '-50';
}
```

```css
html, body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;}
html {
display:table;
}
body{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#back{
font-family: Corbert;
font-style: italic; 
font-size: 2em; 
color: ##006699;
position: relative; 
padding: 30px; 
margin-left: 20px; 
}
td img {
padding: 20px;
width: 500px; 
}
a {
color: #006699;
margin: 0 auto;
text-decoration: none; 
}
a:hover {
color: #8b98a7;
}
p {
position: fixed;
padding: 30px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
clear: both; 
margin-left: 20px; 
}
table {
top: 50%
left: 50% 
position: absolute; 
border:none;
}
.popup {
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
z-index: 0;  
overflow-y: scroll;
top: 5px; left: 5px;
background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
#popup1, #popup2, #popup3, #popup4 {
visibility: hidden;
width:800px!important;
padding:25px;
height:auto; 
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="../index.html">
<p id="back"> LEAH GOTCHEL </p></a>

<!-- hidden popup images -->
<img class="popup" id="popup1" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" alt="daisies" onclick="hideMe(this);"    />
<img class="popup" id="popup2" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" alt="snowdrops" onclick="hideMe(this);"/>
<img class="popup" id="popup3" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" onclick="hideMe(this);"/>
<img class="popup" id="popup4" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg" alt="yellowflowers" onclick="hideMe(this);"/>

<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" alt="daisies" id="img01" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage('popup1');"></td>
<td> 
<img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" alt="snowdrops" id="img02" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage('popup2');">       
</td>
<td><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" id="img03" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage('popup3');"></td>
<td><img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg" alt="yellowflowers" id="img04" style="cursor:pointer" 
onclick="showImage('popup4');">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="caption">custom window bench: oak, poplar </p>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll note that your javascript is neatly condensed into three functions, and that your ids are now unique. I got rid of the extra divs,  why did you need them anyway, when you could just click on the image to hide it? Over-complicating things. Obviously the images have been replaced with dummy images from my website, but sure it works!

Comment: try this code https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/5nee1k3q/ I haven't put my own images in it to test it, but copy and paste

Comment: hi thank you! seems very close, but no cigar. i'm working on dreamweaver and it works fine in design view but when on the browser only the largeImgPanel shows up with no image. seems like I have to adjust something in CSS but not sure what yet. thanks for your super helpful response!

Comment: You're welcome! If you post your full css/ HTML,  css in particular, I'd be able to help more. Cos I tried to recreate but couldn't due to limited resources :(

Comment: You can edit your existing question. No need to post a new one.

Comment: ok i posted the full CSS and HTML - i did make one adjustment so that the popup images are now appearing on top of the largeImgPanel but unfortunately i'm still having the same problem as before! the first image (img01) is the only one that appears and i'm pretty sure it's just blocking the other popups from view

Comment: just to note i didn't include your adjustments when i updated the html!

Comment: @leahg hey, i just saw this note now, ok cool i'll have a look

Comment: @leahg by the way, i find it easier to use display:none rather than visibility:hidden;

Comment: @leahg are you using internet explorer or something? cos i'm using the latest chrome, and the onclick event never happened, not with your old code or your new. I think its something to do with the table. Some browsers don't support them now. I'm going to put it in an unstyled list, inline-block, and see if that'll make a difference

Comment: oh that sounds like a good idea! that's weird, i'm also on chrome and the event is running fine on the new (your) code - not on the old code that's listed here though.

Comment: Hmm yeah I wondered, cos I  tried your old code last night ( it's  7.45 here am. Will revert. You do have multiple functions with the same name tho, I saw this. You can re use a function, that is why we use them. Pass an argument!!! Then you'd have more luck. Anyway, breakfast first, code after!!?

Comment: wow you are a complete wiz!!! thanks so much for your help! looks absolutely perfect. thanks for cluing me in about where i went off... and yes sorry about the delayed responses, looks like we're working on pretty opposite schedules/sides of the pond. looking forward to getting my site up and running... i owe you one!!